# Bind ng-model name and ng-click inside ng-repeat in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I need to know naming convention for the ng-model and ng-click inside the ng-repeat. And also need to know how to use each model name and ng-click function in the controller. I have given a sample code to show you what I exactly need know.

```
<input name="" type="button" ng-click="incrementRoomCount()">
<div ng-repeat="student in studentList">
 <div>Room <span>{{student.studentCount}}</span></div>
 <div>
     <input name="" type="button" ng-click="removeStudent()">
     <input name="adult" type="text" ng-model="noOfStudents">
     <input name="" type="button" class="roomPopupPlusBtn" ng-click="addStudent()">
 </div>
 <div ng-repeat="studentAge in studentList">
    <div ng-show="studentAgeWrapper">
     <select name="age">
      <option ng-repeat="studentAge in ['20','21','22','23','24','25']">{{studentAge}</option>                   
     </select>              
     </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: When repeating you need to add the student identifier which could be an idea. What is the structure of the student object? Example if student.id is the identifier then you can add the following removeStudent(student.id). You need also add the data attribute data="{{student.id}}" on the input tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

The following fiddle demonstrates how to call functions when repeating over items. You could also just pass in an id to the remove function.

```
<input value="Remove From Room" type="button" ng-click="removeStudent(student)"/>
        </div>

$scope.removeStudent = function(student) {
angular.forEach($scope.studentList, function(checkStudent, index) {
    if (checkStudent.id === student.id) {
        $scope.studentList.splice(index,1);    
    }
});
```

};

http://jsfiddle.net/houston88/ab23r/1/