# Using ng-click inside np-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, model-binding, angularjs-ng-click

I'm trying to implement a shortlisting functionality in a case where I'm using `ng-click` inside `ng-repeat`.

While the `$index` is being displayed correctly outside the `ng-click`, `$index` is only the index of the last object in the `JSON` array in all the cases where the html is generated using ng-repeat.

I was expecting the respective `venue` or `venue.id` to be passed as an argument to `shortlistThis()`. I'm guessing that this could be an issue related to event binding.

Can someone help me understand what's going wrong here and probably a better way to do this if possible.

I did try checking this [Bind ng-model name and ng-click inside ng-repeat in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21385164/bind-ng-model-name-and-ng-click-inside-ng-repeat-in-angularjs) The fiddle here works just fine but, mine doesn't.

Update: I've found something interesting here. When the shortlist button is placed just under the ng-repeat, it work just as intended. But when, nested inside a div with a ng-class, it isn't working as intended. Can anyone explain and suggest a fix for this ?

```js
//locationsapp.js var locationsApp = angular.module('locationsApp', []);


var venues = [{
  id: "Flknm",
  name: "ship",
}, {
  id: "lelp",
  name: "boat",
}, {
  id: "myp",
  name: "yacht",
}, ];

var shortlistedVenues = [];


var locationsApp = angular.module('locationsApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);



locationsApp.controller("getvenues", function($scope) {
  $scope.venues = venues;
  $scope.shortlistThis = function(venue) {
    console.log(venue);
    if (shortlistedVenues.indexOf(venue) == -1) {
      shortlistedVenues.push(venue);
      //alert('If');
    } else {
      console.log('already shortlisted')
    }
  };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div class="locations" ng-app="locationsApp">
  <div ng-controller="getvenues">
    <div ng-repeat="venue in venues" ng-mouseover="" class="venue">
      <div ng-controller="manageInfo">
        <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="control" ng-click="showInfo()">
          </div>
          <div class="maps" class="info">
            <div ng-class="class">
              <div class="close-info" ng-click="hideInfo()">
                <i class="fa fa-times">
                </i>
              </div>
              <div class="row full-venue-contents" ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
                <div class="">
                  <div class="row-fluid myclass">
                    <div class="button-holder">
                      <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 text-center btn-grid">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-sup" ng-click="shortlistThis(venue)">
                            Shortlist{{$index}}
                          </button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- End of Full Info Container -->
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="compare">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-sup">
            Compare ( {{shortlistedVenues.length}} )
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: using multiple `ng-app` on same html,does it ever worked? For that do create a single module and then append it at once by injecting dependency into it...

Comment: My bad with not checking the usage of ng-app again.The second ng-app is just there but no where used. The code is functional. The only issue here is getting the respective index/venue to be passed as an argument using ng-click. When tried, it passes the index of last array in all the ng-click cases.

Comment: try `$parent.$index` it should work.

Comment: no luck with $parent.$index I'm still trying to find a solution for this.

Comment: I have created fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/ab23r/21/.. can you please eloborate now what is the problem here?

Comment: Updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ab23r/21/ Click on any location on the right, then hit the shortlist button on the right pane. It should show you an alert. Note: Please zoom out while trying the fiddle. it has responsive issues atm.

Comment: why your fiddle is not working, did you missed to update it?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yashwanthm/mos9rvvs/ Please use this fiddle. Thank you for looking into this. The alert value is 7 in all the cases.

Comment: I've found something interesting here. When the shortlist button is placed just under the ng-repeat, it work just as intended. But when, nested inside a div with a ng-class, it isn't working as intended. Can anyone explain and suggest a fix for this ?

Comment: the issue with your button as you made your button position fixed, it showing the 1st button, but clicking on it causing to click last button..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your button div which was `position: fixed`, it is actually showing the 1st button but clicking on it firing last button click, I'd suggest you should suggest you render only the shortlist button which has been selected by you. For that you can use `ng-if` and render those button which `index` is the same as that of selected `$index`

**HTML**

```
<div ng-if="selected==$index" class="button-holder">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 text-center btn-grid">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-sup" 
            ng-click="shortlistThis($parent.$index)">Shortlist{{$index}}</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

& then put `ng-click="selected='$index'"` on `ng-repeat div` like

```
<div ng-repeat="venue in venues" class="venue" ng-click="selected=$index">
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mos9rvvs/6/)

Hope this could help you, Thanks.